# What does "to factor something across" mean?

Tags: soft-question, category-theory, terminology

In the book [*Conceptual mathematics*](http://fef.ogu.edu.tr/matbil/eilgaz/kategori.pdf), by Lawvere et al. it says on page $45$:

> When $B$ is a one-element set, then the possibility of *factoring* a given $h : A \to C$ *across* $B$ is a very drastic restriction on $h$.

What does it mean "to factor something across"? I believe that this terminology wasn't explained before. And why is it called like that?

Comment: The "division problem" : to find the "factors" of a map. To find $f$ and $g$ such that $h=g \circ f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Factor across" here just means solving the "determination" or "choice" problem referred to in the text.  In this case, $h$ "factors across" $B$ if there exists $g:B\to C$ such that $h=g\circ f$, where $f:A\to B$ is the unique map.  The term "factor" here comes from thinking of composition as "multiplication": you are asking whether you can "factor" $h$ as a "product" $g\circ f$.

(I must admit that I have not encountered the exact phrasing "factor across" before.  In my experience, the phrasing "factor through" is much more common.)

Comment: Thanks. I think one could define that $h:A \to C$ *factors across* $B$ if there are two mappings $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$ such that $h=gf$. Also, say that $h$ *factors through* $f$ if there is $g$ such that $h=gf$.

Comment: Yes, that would also be a reasonable interpretation.  But in this case there is only one choice of $f$.  And in general, people usually speak of $h:A\to C$ factoring through $B$ only when they have a fixed choice of $f$ or $g$ in mind already (and so it would be more precise to say "factors through $f$" or "factors through $g$").  When neither map is fixed, the question is usually too broad to be very useful.

Comment: I would guess that "through" is used when what follows is a map and "across" is used when what follows is an object. Also, after some research I would assume that generally, "h factors across B" means as I defined it. In our concrete situation, this means exactly what you said because there is only one choice for f.

Comment: Ok, I'm wrong. "Through" can also be used in the context of objects. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_jargon#Descriptive_informalities